# Control /dev/pts/* assignments

Tags: linux, terminal-server, udev

I am trying to find a way to create a udev rule for a network connected terminal? Basically I need the rule to say a specific MAC address, or IP, is always assigned pseudo terminal /dev/pts/5 for example. We have instances where Thin Clients are used for remote terminal sessions to a Linux server over SSH. Our application allows for specific terminals to be assigned specific hardware devices, printers, weigh scales, etc.. based on the terminal ID. Our older method was with dumb terminals over serial, this made it easy as a serial device is always connected over a static tty port. Network terminals however receive a dynamic pseudo terminal designation of /dev/pts/*. I'm trying to find a way to force each Thin Client to always connect on the same pts port. Perhaps a udev rule is not the right method so I'm open to other suggestions as well.

I've been testing different variations with this basic rule format but so far nothing is working.
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="C8:CB:B8:04:61:87", ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="/dev/pts/5"